# SIGTSTP does not stop foreground process

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to write subshell in linux with `c`. I am compiling it in normal linux terminal and run it like `./shell`. However, I have trouble about `Ctrl-Z` and `Ctrl-C`. When I press the `Ctrl-Z` for example, it stops `./myshell`, but I want to stop process which is in the  `myshell`.

I am setting new process group after the for like:

```
int pid = fork();

if (!setpgid(pid, 0)) {

} else {
    perror("PGID Error: ");

    return(-1);
}
```

After I check is there any `&` sign for background process I understand it is foreground process then I put new process into foreground then I am waiting the finish or stop of process with `waitpid`. Then I put terminal into foreground. In there I am using `sigprocmask` for `SIGTTOU`, otherwise when I try to put my shell again into foreground it stops backs to linux shell.

```
tcsetpgrp(1,getpgid(pid));

waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &intmask, NULL) == -1)
    perror("sigprocmask error: ");

tcsetpgrp(1, shellpid);

kill(shellpid, SIGCONT);

if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &intmask, NULL) == -1)
    perror("sigprocmask error: ");
```

I have also signal handlers to avoid `my_shell` to terminate or stop. I am planning the stop or terminate just foreground processes with `Control-Z` and `Control-C`.

```
void handler_sigint(int signum)
{
    pid_t foregroundpgid=tcgetpgrp(0);

    if(foregroundpgid!=shellpid) {
        kill(foregroundpgid, SIGINT);
    }
}

void handler_sigtstp(int sig)
{
    pid_t foregroundpgid=tcgetpgrp(0);

    if(foregroundpgid!=shellpid) {
        kill(foregroundpgid, SIGSTOP);
    }
}
```

`Control-C` works very well but I have trouble with `Control-Z`. For example I start `cat` in my shell when I press `Control-Z` it just writes `^Z` in the terminal does not stop foreground process. [Please look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNdeM.png)

Comment: Please read up on how to format questions on this site

Comment: I am sorry for this format, I am new here

Comment: No bother - Perhaps worthwhile reading up the help section.

Comment: Answer to the first bit - the shell that you are running your code from is getting the first look in. Try using `exec` to run you program - i.e. remove its influence.

Comment: Actually I have exec part but it is before the putting new process into foreground.

Comment: Use the shells exec - ie. replace it and not run it on your behalf

Comment: - Or easier send the signal direct from a different console

Comment: I did what you said, I am executing program after putting foreground, but still same C-c works C-z not work.

Comment: Sadly, I'm experiencing the same issue with the Ion shell that I'm developing for Redox OS.  C-c works and `waitpid` reflects it, but C-z does nothing at all -- `waitpid` doesn't seem to be notified that the process stopped via a SIGTSTP.